# How to upgrade or downgrade QtCreator?

Tags: software-installation, 15.10, ppa, qt-creator

I am trying to avoid this nasty bug in QtCreator 3.5.1.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-15291

I am quite sure that it is not present either in QtCreator 3.6.1 or in QtCreator 3.4.2. However I am not able to install either of them.

1. The online installers from Qt redirect me to 3.5.1.
2. The offline installers from Qt are only for 64bit Linux
3. I tried addning a PPA, then apt-get update upgrade, but nothing happened

Any guidance is well appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an archive of old Qt version on their website on: http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qtcreator/ or http://download.qt.io/archive/ (for older versions)

If you feel like compiling, you may download any version from github and compile it for yourself: https://github.com/qtproject/qt-creator